# How to import style properties from a .json document into a react component?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

What I would like to do is to import the width, height and style properties into a react component. I will start by showing the .json document with the object properties:

```js
            "manufacturerData": {
                "name": "Duesenberg",
                "articleCount": 0,
                "image": {
                    "file": "duesenberg.jpg",
                    "width": "140",
                    "height": "52",
                    "exists": true
                }
            },
```

I want to import the styles: **width** and the **height** into my image card container, that looks like this:

```js
  return (
    <Card className='my-3 p-3 thumbnail' style={{ width: '14rem' }}>
      <a href={`/articles/${articles.id}`}>
        <Card.Img src={`/images/${articles.image.file}`} variat='top' />
      </a>
    </Card>
  )
```

I cant seem to find anything online be straight forward on how to get this done.
I very much appreciate the help.

Comment: Thank you Chris, It worked perfectly, the path was getting me confused but you right.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  return (
    // by default 'px' units will be assumed. You can add any other unit explicitly
    <Card className='my-3 p-3 thumbnail' style={{ width: articles.image.width }}>
   // <Card className='my-3 p-3 thumbnail' style={{ width: `${articles.image.width}rem` }}>
      <a href={`/articles/${articles.id}`}>
        <Card.Img src={`/images/${articles.image.file}`} variat='top' />
      </a>
    </Card>
  )
```

Comment: Thank you Anurag, nice one, the back-tics was giving me headache. got the style im place -- appreciate the help man :0)